# Defining function through its properties

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I'm interested in defining an abstract function `f[x,y]` in *Mathematica* through its properties only.

For instance, I would like *Mathematica* to know and simplify using `f[a+b,c] = f[a,c] + f[b,c]`, etc.

How should I define a function in this way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may get you started.

```
 Clear[f];
 SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst];
 f[s_Plus, b__] := f[#, b] & /@ List @@ Hold[s][[1]] // Total
 f[a + b + c, d, e]
```

> f[a, d, e] + f[b, d, e] + f[c, d, e]

Answer (score 2):

A generalized approach:

```
ClearAll[f]
e : f[s : (_Plus | _Times | _Dot), b__] := Thread[Unevaluated@e, Head[s]]
```

Now

```
f[a + b, c]
f[a*b, c]
f[a.b, c]
```

returns

```
   f[a, c] + f[b, c]    
   f[a, c] f[b, c]    
   f[a, c].f[b, c]
```

---

### UPDATE

Shorter version:

```
ClearAll[f]
e : f[(s : Plus | Times | Dot)[__], b__] := Thread[Unevaluated@e, s]
```